# Application Stopped while rotating the android device

Tags: android

I have five tabs in my application say A,B,C,D and E.My problem is that application stopped while changing the tab from B to any other tabs and rotating the device into landscape mode or portrait mode.

Error log is

> 08-22 11:27:22.835: E/AndroidRuntime(5992): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   08-22 11:27:22.835: E/AndroidRuntime(5992): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nv.netmdapp1/com.nv.netmdapp1.Home}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   08-22 11:27:22.835: E/AndroidRuntime(5992):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
>   08-22 11:27:22.835: E/AndroidRuntime(5992):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
>   08-22 11:27:22.835: E/AndroidRuntime(5992):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3351)
>   08-22 11:27:22.835: E/AndroidRuntime(5992):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:123)
>   08-22 11:27:22.835: E/AndroidRuntime(5992):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1151)
>   08-22 11:27:22.835: E/AndroidRuntime(5992):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   08-22 11:27:22.835: E/AndroidRuntime(5992):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   08-22 11:27:22.835: E/AndroidRuntime(5992):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
>   08-22 11:27:22.835: E/AndroidRuntime(5992):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   08-22 11:27:22.835: E/AndroidRuntime(5992):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   08-22 11:27:22.835: E/AndroidRuntime(5992):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>   08-22 11:27:22.835: E/AndroidRuntime(5992):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
>   08-22 11:27:22.835: E/AndroidRuntime(5992):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   08-22 11:27:22.835: E/AndroidRuntime(5992): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   08-22 11:27:22.835: E/AndroidRuntime(5992):     at com.nv.netmdapp1.ScheduleDailyView.onActivityCreated(ScheduleDailyView.java:89)
>   08-22 11:27:22.835: E/AndroidRuntime(5992):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1468)

Java code given below.

> public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>           super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
>           dailyFragment = (SherlockFragment) Fragment.instantiate(appContext, AppointmentDailyView.class.getName(),arguments);
>           weeklyFragment=(SherlockFragment) Fragment.instantiate(appContext, AppointmentWeeklyView.class.getName(),arguments);

```
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment lastFrag = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("appointmentFrag");
    if(lastFrag!=null)
        ft.remove(lastFrag);
    ft.replace(R.id.ll_appointment_layout, dailyFragment);
    ft.commit();
}
@Override
public void onClick(View view) 
{
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment lastFrag = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("appointmentFrag");
    if(lastFrag!=null)
        ft.remove(lastFrag);
    if(view==btnDaily)
        ft.replace(R.id.ll_appointment_layout, dailyFragment);
    else
        ft.replace(R.id.ll_appointment_layout, weeklyFragment);
    ft.commit();
}
```

When clicking Tab C this part is executed.But while rotating the device control goes to onActivityCreated() of Tab B.
Here null pointer exception occurring  line ScheduleDailyView.java:89 is associated with Tab B.But while rotating the device control goes from tab C and D to this file.What is the reason?

Comment: Give us some code. you have a NPE ScheduleDailyView.java:89

Comment: NullPointerException  at com.nv.netmdapp1.ScheduleDailyView.onActivityCreated(ScheduleDailyView.java:89)

Comment: Reason is a NullPointerException. Some object is null and you try used him.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 08-20 16:54:43.319: E/AndroidRuntime(5646): at com.nv.netmdapp1.ScheduleDailyView.onActivityCreated(ScheduleDailyView.java:89) 08-20`. Note that `89` is the line number.

Comment: Edited my question.Please look at it.

Answer (score 3):

Add the `android:configChanges="orientation"` in the android manifest, it handles the orientation change event in application.

Manifest:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" 
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
```

Hope helpful to you..

Answer (score 0):

Rotating the Device restarts your app again:

OnActivityCreated Method is called and you are getting a null pointer exception here:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-20 16:54:43.319: E/AndroidRuntime(5646):     at com.nv.netmdapp1.ScheduleDailyView.onActivityCreated(ScheduleDailyView.java:89)
```

Check what is null here, also you can avoid restarting your activity on rotation by handling configuration changes.